# Zoho OAuth 2.0 Refresh token multiple times

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, access-token, zoho, refresh-token

I am using Zoho OAuth 2.0 and I have followed the steps in https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/v2/#oauth-request to get the access token and refresh token. However I have some problems.

Here is a scenario:

```
1. Get authorization token
2. From authorization token, get  access token and refresh token.
3. After one hour, I use the refresh token. (then I receive a new access token) - As stated here https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/v2/#refreshing-tokens
4. After that, another hour, how is it possible for me to get another access token? As refresh token expires in an hour (similar to access token I assume).
5. When I refresh token, only a new access token is given but not a new refresh token. So after one hour I cannot do another refresh again.
```

Anyone have any idea how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar use case myself and I must say it is poorly documented. Your application should have a 'static' refresh token and use it to generate a new access token every hour.

> Auth ----> Refresh --(every hour)--> Access

So for my back end I'm using a pre-generated refresh token and generating an access token when the time's up for that hour. Use this access token to have a normal interaction with the API.

I recommend you read the docs from multiples Zoho modules as they are poor and you may need more than one example to really understand it even if you just use one module (Most of the time the auth part is really the same). You can start [here](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/api/using-oauth-2.html) and [here](https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/v2/#OAuth2_0).

Answer (score 0):

Zoho provides refresh token only one time with one account. so we have to save that refresh token to get new access token.

Answer (score 0):

use this function to create a new access token. You have to call this method every hour before the access token gets expired. It generates a new access token for you

```
function generateAuthTokenfromRefreshToken(test){    ZCRMRestClient.generateAuthTokenfromRefreshToken(process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL_ADDRESS,process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN).then(function(auth_response){
         process.env.OAUTH_TOKEN=auth_response.access_token;         
         logger.log('info', ` new_outh_token :${auth_response.access_token}`);                 
 })
```